# Informix CDC — convert decimal, date, etc from bytearray

Tags: c#, informix

I try to work with Informix Change Data Capture in C#! The CDC is running and I get data on Insert, Update, Delete, but I'm not able to convert some data from bytearray.

Does anyone know how to convert these values in c#?

- bytearray 62,28,0,0 should be decimal(6,2) -72.00
- bytearray 193,72,0,0 should be decimal(6,2) 72.00
- bytearray 193,1,18,0,0,0,0,0 should be decimal(14,4) 1.1800
- bytearray 194,1,0,0,0,0,0 should be decimal(12,0) 100
- bytearray 194,4,1,67,89,0,0,0,0 should be decimal(15,4) 401.6789
- bytearray 0,0,166,33 should be date 09.06.16 (DMY format)

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with byte arrays for the data types pushes you into some deep byte-mangling.

#### DATE

The DATE type is much the easier of the two to handle.

- DATE values are 4-byte integers.
- The store the count of the number of days since the reference date, which is 1899-12-31 (so day 1 was 1900-01-01).
- The format is big-endian.

Your data is (decimal) bytes 0, 0, 166, 33, which maps to the decimal integer 42529 (or hexadecimal 0xA621), and when I run:

```
sqlcmd -d stores -e 'select date(42529) from dual'
```

I get back the answer:

```
2016-06-09
```

which is what you expected.  (The SQLCMD program is available from the International Informix User Group ([IIUG](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL)) Software Repository in the ESQL/C section.  It is nothing to do with Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the same name.)  I work with `DBDATE=y4md-` in the environment, hence the date format.  And I have a one row table called `dual` in my `stores` database; you can use `sysmaster:sysdual` instead, if you prefer.  Negative dates are valid; they use the so-called 'proleptic' Gregorian calendar and do not revert to the Julian calendar before 1752, 1584, or any other date.  The maximum valid date is 9999-12-31.

#### DECIMAL

The DECIMAL type is considerably more complex.  The on-disk format is controlled by the type qualifiers.  There's a header, `decimal.h`, in the `$INFORMIXDIR/incl/esql` directory which contains the information:

```
/*
 * Packed Format  (format in records in files)
 *
 *    First byte =
 *        top 1 bit = sign 0=neg, 1=pos
 *        low 7 bits = Exponent in excess 64 format
 *    Rest of bytes = base 100 digits in 100 complement format
 *    Notes --  This format sorts numerically with just a
 *              simple byte by byte unsigned comparison.
 *              Zero is represented as 80,00,00,... (hex).
 *              Negative numbers have the exponent complemented
 *              and the base 100 digits in 100's complement
 */
```

Some code I wrote related to this adds the information:

```
**    --    Negative numbers have the exponent complemented (exp = (~exp
**          & 0x7F)) and the base 100 digits in 100's complement.
**          That is, last non-zero digit is subtracted from 100;
**          previous digits from 99.
```

If you're good at parsing densely written English, that is actually a fairly accurate description of what goes on, but it takes a lot of parsing.

Let's look at your first two values:

- bytearray 62,28,0,0 should be decimal(6,2) -72.00
- bytearray 193,72,0,0 should be decimal(6,2) 72.00

The value for a decimal has a the sign bit and an exponent in the first byte (the 62 = 0x3E and 193 = 0xC1 bytes here), and then the numbers in decimal digits in the subsequent bytes.  A DECIMAL(6,2) value has one to four decimal digits before the decimal point, and zero to two after the decimal point, for a total of 6 decimal digits, or three centesimal (base-100) digits.  That's why those two values use 4 bytes on disk.

The 0xC1 byte has the leading bit set to indicate a positive number.  The exponent is 0x41, which is decimal 65.  That's in 'excess 64' mode, so the actual exponent value is 1, which means that the decimal point occurs after the first byte.  The number 72 is clearly visible.  Thus 0xC1, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00 does indeed map to `+72.00`.  Similarly, the 28 is the 100s complement of 72, and the first bit of the exponent is 0 so the value is negative.  The exponent value 0x3E is indeed the bitwise inversion of 0x41 masked with 0x7F:

```
0100 0001    0x41
1011 1110    ~0x41
0011 1110    (~0x41) & 0x7F
```

In C (not C# — I don't know what facilities are available for doing this in C#), I created this program.  The `lddecimal()` function is the standard (Informix-provided) function for converting from the on-disk DECIMAL format to the in-memory format (`dec_t` — a C structure type).   The `dump_decimal()` and `dec_fix()` functions are not standard (but you can find code for them with the source for SQLCMD).  The first prints the information in the structure in an unambiguous format.  The second prints the value represented in the structure as a fixed-point decimal (the third argument of `1` indicates that the sign should always be printed).

```
#include "decsci.h"
#include "dumpesql.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

struct dec_info
{
    int length;
    int dec_places;
    char bytes[9];
};

static const struct dec_info values[] =
{
    { 4, 2, {  62, 28,  0,  0,  0 } },
    { 4, 2, { 193, 72,  0,  0,  0 } },
    { 8, 4, { 193,  1, 18,  0,  0 } },
    { 7, 0, { 194,  1,  0,  0,  0 } },
    { 9, 4, { 194,  4,  1, 67, 89 } },
};

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM(values); i++)
    {
        dec_t dv = { 0 };
        printf("\nBytes:  ");
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++)
            printf(" 0x%.2X", values[i].bytes[j] & 0xFF);
        putchar('\n');

        lddecimal(values[i].bytes, values[i].length, &dv);

        char ds[60];
        dec_fix(&dv, values[i].dec_places, 1, ds, sizeof(ds));
        printf("Decimal: %s\n", ds);

        char tag[20];
        snprintf(tag, sizeof(tag), "Example %d", i);
        dump_decimal(stdout, tag, &dv);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The output from this code is:

```
Bytes:   0x3E 0x1C 0x00 0x00
Decimal: -72.00
DECIMAL: Example 0 -- address 0x7FFF59282400
E:   +1, S = 0 (-), N =  1, M = 72 [ unused:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]

Bytes:   0xC1 0x48 0x00 0x00
Decimal: +72.00
DECIMAL: Example 1 -- address 0x7FFF59282400
E:   +1, S = 1 (+), N =  1, M = 72 [ unused:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]

Bytes:   0xC1 0x01 0x12 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Decimal: +1.1800
DECIMAL: Example 2 -- address 0x7FFF59282400
E:   +1, S = 1 (+), N =  2, M = 01 18 [ unused:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]

Bytes:   0xC2 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Decimal: +100
DECIMAL: Example 3 -- address 0x7FFF59282400
E:   +2, S = 1 (+), N =  1, M = 01 [ unused:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]

Bytes:   0xC2 0x04 0x01 0x43 0x59 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Decimal: +401.6789
DECIMAL: Example 4 -- address 0x7FFF59282400
E:   +2, S = 1 (+), N =  4, M = 04 01 67 89 [ unused:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
```

Converting that to C# will require expertise I don't have, but it gives you indications of what you need to do or find.

Note that DATETIME and INTERVAL types also use DECIMAL in their on-disk and in-memory representations.